# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, vitamio

My application consists of `ffmpeg`, `javacv-android-arm`, `opencv-2.4.8-android-arm` (.so files) and `javacpp`, `javacv` jars. Its working good.

After that I add the `Vitamio library` application to my application.`Vitamio` consists some jars like as `ffmpeg` etc in it. After adding that I am getting an error like "class not found exception".

And my error message is:
[link](http://pastie.org/8697441)

i am getting error in this code:

```
 private void initRecorder() {

    Log.w(LOG_TAG,"init recorder");

    if (yuvIplimage == null) {
        yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2); //error here.
 //       Log.i(LOG_TAG, "create yuvIplimage");
    }

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ffmpeg_url: " + ffmpeg_link);
    recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(ffmpeg_link, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1);
    recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264) ;
    recorder.setFormat("flv");
    recorder.setSampleRate(sampleAudioRateInHz);
    // Set in the surface changed method
   // myPreference.getString("rtmp_url", "sample1");
    recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate);

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "recorder initialize success");

    audioRecordRunnable = new AudioRecordRunnable();
    audioThread = new Thread(audioRecordRunnable);
}
```

Please help me

Comment: @M D, The link for error message is gone. Please edit again and put the link.

Comment: In your log: saying libopencv_core.so file missing. Check your Android.mk file

Comment: This is probably related to this issue: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=199

Answer (score 1):

In error log

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libopencv_core.so" needed by "libjniopencv_core.so"; caused by library "libopencv_core.so" not found
```

Its seems like you have not loaded `libopencv_core` in your application.
Load this library using

```
System.loadLibrary("libopencv_core")
```

before use any function of this library. It would be better if you load this in `onCreate()` of main activity.

Comment: actually if i remove the vitamio library its working.i think due to some conflict between these i am getting this error.

Comment: i update my code see it once.I follow this [link](http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg/).its working good after adding this vitamio only i am getting error in this code.

Comment: @Seshu I am not sure you were right that both library have same `ffmpeg` which is conflicting.

Comment: try adding a couple more libraries in that list, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26273824/979369

Answer (score 0):

1. Class not found Exception comes when you have not declare your activity in the manifest file.
2. Sometimes it can also be remove by cleaning the project then
      Go to Properties: Java Build Path
                 In this tick the android Private Libraries
                 Move src and gen folder at top.
                 The order will be firsr src folder and then gen folder
                 Also tick the all libraries that are included duringly adding your jar file

Answer (score 0):

Add the following block to your code

```
static
{
  System.loadLibrary("libopencv_core")
}
```

As it is a `static` block it will be called before anything else and your library will be loaded. Do this for all the other native libraries that you want to use too.

Comment: actually if i remove the vitamio library its working.i think due to some conflict between these i am getting this error.