# UnsatisfiedLinkError for libopencv_core.so while .apk holds this library

Tags: android, javacv

I want to use JavaCv with my App on Android.
Therefore I followed the advice here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv on how to install Android 2.2 or newer. As a result the following libraries can be found under **\libs\armeabi**: 
`libjniopencv_core.so`
`libopencv_core.so`

All classes of both libraries are also present in the classes.dex file of my .apk.
And still i get the following exception:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libopencv_core.so" needed by "libjniopencv_core.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libopencv_core.so" not found`

I tried loading libopencv_core.so via

```
System.loadLibrary("libopencv_core")
```

and

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv_core")
```

with the same outcome..

Any hint on how to solve this issue would be appreciated.

**Edit1:**

I had a look to see which .so files could actually be found under `/data/app-lib/ccc.android.myappname`...

Despite libopencv_core.so and other files can be found under `lib/armeabi/` in my .apk only some of them are available for my activity under `/data/app-lib/ccc.android.myappname`. The others are just ignored for some unknown reason.

Can somebody help, i have no idea what is going on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution i found:

I discussed this matter on the JavaCv board on Github:

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/28

The Issue might be history with the next release, but for the meantime do as follows:

Before using JavaCv for the first time run:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("tbb");
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_core");
        System.loadLibrary("jniopencv_core");
}
```

On some devices (or occasion) the intended load order get mixed up...

Comment: Non of the three libraries found for me.